Checkov Docker File throwing new line unexpected error
curl -sSLo get_kustomize.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/master/hack/install_kustomize.sh; \
    chmod 700 get_kustomize.sh; \
    ./get_kustomize.sh; mv /kustomize /usr/bin/kustomize; \
    rm ./get_kustomize.sh; \

Using the above curl commands but getting Syntax Error : newline unexpected.
Here is the docker file : https://github.com/bridgecrewio/checkov/blob/main/Dockerfile
 Incorrect Line Endings: If the file was created on a Windows system, it might have Windows-style line endings (\r\n instead of \n). You can fix this by converting the line endings to Unix format.

bash
Copy code
dos2unix your_script.sh
Or, if dos2unix isn't available, use sed:

bash
Copy code
sed -i 's/\r$//' your_script.sh
Incorrect Shebang: Ensure the first line of the script has the correct shebang (#!/bin/bash or #!/bin/sh).

Unintended Characters or Formatting: Sometimes, unexpected spaces, tabs, or other characters in the script can cause syntax issues. Use a text editor with syntax highlighting to look for these or try copying the contents of the script into a clean file.

File Permissions: Ensure the script is executable:

bash
Copy code
chmod +x your_script.sh
After trying these steps, rerun the script to see if the error is resolved

